# How do you create a hermetic LLVM toolchain that lives outside of /usr?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, clang, llvm

I'd like our product's builds to use a more recent version of Clang/LLVM than what is available in our distribution's package manager.  I built it from source, making sure to include libc++, libc++abi, compiler-rt, clang, and lld.  When configuring the project, I used `-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/some/folder/under/my/repo`.

After building, I `ninja install`ed it.  When I try to compile a file using this version of clang, and passing `--sysroot /some/folder/under/my/repo`, it is able to find libc++ and libc headers, but not system headers.  For example, the first file that it can't find is `features.h`, which is under /usr/include and is not part of LLVM.

I tried symlinking a few of these and was planning to check in the symlinks, but eventually I reasoned with myself "Why bother, I can just `-I/usr/include`, because the sysroot would take priority anyway."

But even this is not enough.  I next encountered `sys/cdefs.h`.  This file is actually under `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/cdefs.h`, so even a `-I/usr/include` isn't sufficient.

I can certainly keep going down this path and copying/symlinking every single dependency from /usr/include over to my new sysroot, but I can't help but think I'm going about this all wrong.  That said, asking every engineer in the company to build clang from source and install it to /usr is a non-starter.  Is there any way to check in binaries into a repo, have the build pull the compiler, headers, libs, etc straight out of the repo, but still pull non-LLVM system headers from /usr/include?

Comment: At this stage you may want to start looking at containers: https://llvm.org/docs/Docker.html

Comment: On my system, `clang` uses `-internal-isystem /usr/local/include -internal-isystem /usr/lib/llvm-11/lib/clang/11.1.0/include -internal-externc-isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -internal-externc-isystem /include -internal-externc-isystem /usr/include`.  You probably need to add all these switches, adjusting `/usr/lib/llvm-11/` to your local path. Probably a better way is to configure the clang *at build time* to use your private libc++ and the rest of the dependencies.

Comment: If you do keep going, you'll either discover that your software depends on things you don't think it should use, or else you'll reach the end quickly and have a complete picture of what your code requires. Once that is done and you have the list, building a package with "your" LLVM is simple (I've built both .deb and .rpm packages).